# Shrinking div's background color with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS to generate the transparent grey box behind the text "branch out of the 9-5" in the image below:

```
.page-id-5 .col-md-8{
    background: rgb(70, 70, 70); /* Fallback for older browsers without RGBA-support */
    background: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.3);
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

But the box is way too wide. I've tried using "width" to make it narrower, but it messes up the whole design. How can I adjust the width of the background box without changing the text? Live example here: https://goprune.com

[image]

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
.page-id-5 .col-md-8{
    background: rgb(70, 70, 70); /* Fallback for older browsers without RGBA-support */
    background: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.3);
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: auto !important;     /* Add */
    margin-left: 0 !important;  /* add */
}
```

And also add:

```
.page-id-5 .top-parallax-section{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

I tried directly on your website, via the code inspector... So it should work.

Having an auto width to that div will fix the the extra padding. And `flex` will center the div correctly.

The `!important;` are to make sure to overide the bootstrap rules. ;)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to put it slightly wider?

Comment: You can add some padding... Note that padding can take 4 values: top right bottom left. So you could try `padding: 25px 5px 10px 5px;` and remove the `padding-left` and `padding-bottom`...

Comment: Make sure to test the mobile sizes... And fix the media rules accordingly. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, change the style into

```css
.page-id-5 .col-md-8{
    background: rgb(70, 70, 70); /* Fallback for older browsers without RGBA-support */
    background: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.3);
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: auto; /* have space based on text */
    margin: 0 auto; /* center div */
    display: table; /* to overlap the current displaying options provided by parents*/
    float: none; /* ignore float option */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the wordpress theme you are using is using a bit of dated code.

You probably can't simply change `.page-id-5 .col-md-8` as it seems like quite a generic className, so I suggest the following which seems more solid imho.

1. The first part is setting the box. Making sure you can easily center the title box bot horizontally as vertically.
2. The second part is making use of the box provided and overwriting code which might stand in the way.
3. Last part is making sure you can improve layout a bit.

A unique piece of the code is `.top-parallax-section`.
So what you can use is:

```css
.small-screen .top-parallax-section {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  height: 336px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.top-parallax-section .text-center {
  background: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.3);
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  width: auto;
}

.top-parallax-section .mb32 p,
.top-parallax-section .mb32 {
  margin: 0
}
```